# close windows pop up

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i have a problem with the close pop up window. i have a page with a button ADD when I click the Add button I call a pop window like this

```
 <script>
    var page = "http://Test.aspx"
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
              .html('<iframe style="border: 0px;  " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
              .dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  modal: true,
                  height: 550,
                  width: 650,
                  title: "ADD Something",
                  close: function (ev, ui) { window.location.reload() }
              });
    $dialog.dialog('close');

    function Insert() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    }
<script/>
```

When i fill the form i click the button Submit inside the popUp. the problem is that the pop up doesn't close i try this on the submit click :

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    Response.Write("alert('Updated Successfully');");
    Response.Write("document.location.href='Test.aspx';");
    Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

after save the page redirect inside the pop up... i want to close the pop up and than redirect to the parent page

Comment: If the iframe content is from the same server, call a function in the parent window. for example`parent.$dialog.dialog('close');`

Comment: Thnx for the answer it work for closing the pop up but when i click the ADD button again the pop up show me the redirected page Test.aspx :(

Comment: And what should it show?

Comment: Thnx....worked perfectly i just added this:  close: function (ev, ui) { window.location.reload() } in the dialog to force postback after Save button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iframe content is from the same server, call a function in the parent window. for example

```
parent.$dialog.dialog('close');
```